# How to get typescript definitions for graphql query tag with variables?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to generate typescript definitions for my graphql tagged queries through apollo-cli (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output). And they are not generating for a query with variables in `${}` in the template string. Is there any way to make it work?

For the tag function I'm using a custom module([gqutils](https://github.com/smartprix/gqutils)). I have set the tag to `$gql.tag` in the options. It successfully generates types for queries without any variables in them.

I tried looking for a way to provide a custom parser so I could maybe execute the template string and get the raw value. Is there anything equivalent to [custom document loader](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/documents-field#custom-document-loader) in apollo client.

This is the code snippet:

```js
const docType = {
    PRODUCT: 'Product',
};

const query = $gql.tag`
  query searchProducts (
    $categoryId: IntID,
  ){
    searchProducts(categoryId: $categoryId, docType: ${docType.PRODUCT}) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        id,
        name,
      }
  }`;
```

`apollo` cli doesn't generate any errors but just silently ignores the file from the types output.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, since Apollo-cli generates the types from the GraphQL schema, and you are putting a varible in it, which does not translate to a graphql type `docType: ${docType.PRODUCT}` it is unable to parse it.
If the doctype is a graphql enum, you do not need to make a specific string object for it.

Consider this:

```
""" graphql schema enum """
enum DocTypes {
PRODUCT
...
}
```

```js
// the frontend query
const query = gql `
  query searchProducts (
    $categoryId: IntID,
    $docType: DocTypes
  ){
    searchProducts(categoryId: $categoryId, docType: $docType) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        id,
        name,
      }
  }
`
```

In above query you would put the docType enum in the query variables.

When the apollo CLI runs now, it will from the graphql schema enum generate the needed enum on the frontend as well.

As a general rule of thumb, i would recommend not putting computed values in your graphql query strings, as these are hard to parse for any graphql integration tools.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of passing the enums in variables, even though I'm passing everything else as variables now. This would solve this case. Thanks!

Comment: So the standard is using static strings for queries if one wants generated types?